# How to make CKEditor insert list into paragraph?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have some paragraph in CKEditor and I want to insert bulleted list into it.

But it seems like it is impossible: clicking List icon turns my paragraph into list, but does not insert the list into the existing paragraph.
So I have to switch to Source mode to do it manually.

How to make CKEditor insert the new list into the existing paragraph?

Comment: try to go to end of the paragraph and then click on list .. i have tested it, see if it helps ...

Comment: it does not work, please see the video: http://take.ms/TlHrl

Comment: why are you using show blocks button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to insert list into paragraph per [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element):

> A p element's end tag can be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, details, div, dl, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, menu, nav, **ol**, p, pre, section, table, or **ul** element

What's more, browsers replace `<p><ul></ul></p>` with `<p></p><ul></ul><p></p>`, so it's really not possible to do that. Therefore CKEditor 4 does not allow it.

There is also en example inside the specification how to link paragraph with list, in "Note" section:

```
<p>For instance, this fantastic sentence has bullets relating to</p>
<ul>
    <li>wizards,
    <li>faster-than-light travel, and
    <li>telepathy,
</ul>
<p>and is further discussed below.</p>
```